# Write text in the middle of the rectangle in line graph android

Tags: canvas, graphics, line, android-canvas, draw

I am trying to print 'off' in a rectangle in the range where there is no data in the line chart. I draw a rectangle between the end point of the data in the graph and the first point where the data is re-rendered.

But I can not write 'off' in the middle of the whole rectangle on each phone. On some phones 'off' is below or above the rectangle.

*Maybe I can tell what I mean better with this picture:*
[image: Maybe I can tell what I mean better with this picture]

I draw the chart and the rectangle into the code as follows :

```
int i;
    for( i=0; i<totalYvalues.size() ;i++)
    {

        if(totalYvalues.get(i)>=110)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.viitaButtonGreen));
        }
        else if( totalYvalues.get(i)>=80 &&  totalYvalues.get(i)<110)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(GRAY);
        }
        else if( totalYvalues.get(i)<80)
        {
            mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }

        if(i == first) //no data
        {
            canvas.drawRect(xVals.get(i), 70, xVals.get(last),totalYvalues.get(last)+30, rectPaint); // ilk parametre genişliği artırıyor, ikinci yüksekliği artırıyor
            canvas.save();
            drawText(canvas, xVals, totalYvalues, i);
            i= last;
        }
        else
        {  // here i am drawing graph with points. (for colorful line chart)
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawCircle( xVals.get(i), totalYvalues.get(i), 3f, mPaint);
        }
    }
```

And drawText(..) method as follows:

```
public  void drawText(Canvas canvas, ArrayList<Float> xVals, ArrayList<Integer> totalYvalues, int i)
{
    // Text coordinates as follows
    Float x = xVals.get(first)  ;
    Integer y = ( totalYvalues.get(last)+30 +  totalYvalues.get(first) ) /2;

    mPaint.setColor(GRAY);
        mPaint.setTextSize(25);

    canvas.translate(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.rotate(-180f);
    int cx = canvas.getWidth()/ 2;
    int cy =canvas.getHeight() / 2;
    canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, cx, cy);

    canvas.translate(x, y);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawText("OFF", 0, y, mPaint);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.restore();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.scale(1,-1);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.save();

}
```

How can I ensure that the text in the rectangle is exactly in the middle of each phone?  If you help, i will be really appreciative.